# Matlab - selection of numbers for equation

Tags: matlab, equation

I trying to select numbers in order to solve the equation. Here is my code:

```
clc;
clear;
y0_star = 1;
p1 = 1;
p2 = 1;
p3 = 1;
y01_2 = 0;
y02_2 = 0;
y03_2 = 0;
iter_cnt = 0;
while (y0_star > 0.5) && (p1 + p2 + p3 ~= 1)
    y0_star = 1 - 1 / (p1/(1 - y01_2) + p2/(1 - y02_2) + p3/(1 - y03_2));

    if (y0_star < 0.5) && (p1 + p2 + p3 == 1) 
        disp('no errors')
        break
    else
        p1 = rand;
        p2 = rand;
        p3 = rand;
        y01_2 = rand;
        y02_2 = rand;
        y03_2 = rand;
    end

    iter_cnt = iter_cnt + 1;
    if iter_cnt > 10^6
        disp('error')
        break
    end
 end
```

This code does not work properly. 
Values p1, p2, p3, y0_star, y02_2, y03_2 should be in the range [0, 1]. And p1 + p2 + p3 should equals 1. Also I want y0_star < 0.5. How I can do it? It does not means that every selected number should be random. I also tried to find some information about solving linear equations in Matlab. But I found information for only systems of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why this isn't working is because you're not ensuring that `p1 + p2 + p3 = 1`.  What you should do is when you find `p1`, `p2` and `p3`, you should divide each of these constants by the sum of all these numbers.  This will ensure that `p1 + p2 + p3 = 1`.  With this, you can eliminate the checks to see if the values sum to 1.  As such, this is your modified code where I have indicated where you need to change:

```
clc;
clear;
y0_star = 1;
p1 = 1;
p2 = 1;
p3 = 1;
y01_2 = 0;
y02_2 = 0;
y03_2 = 0;
iter_cnt = 0;
while (y0_star > 0.5) %// Change - no need to check for sum not equaling to 1
    y0_star = 1 - 1 / (p1/(1 - y01_2) + p2/(1 - y02_2) + p3/(1 - y03_2));

    if (y0_star < 0.5) %// Change - no need to check if sum equals 1 since we're normalizing
        disp('no errors')
        break
    else
        p1 = rand;
        p2 = rand;
        p3 = rand;
        s = p1 + p2 + p3; %// Change - Find sum of p1 + p2 + p3
        p1 = p1 / s; %// Change - Divide by sum to ensure sum is 1
        p2 = p2 / s;
        p3 = p3 / s;
        y01_2 = rand;
        y02_2 = rand;
        y03_2 = rand;
    end

    iter_cnt = iter_cnt + 1;
    if iter_cnt > 10^6
        disp('error')
        break
    end
 end
```

Running the above code, this is what I get for all of the variables:

```
p1 =

    0.3114

p2 =

    0.3476

p3 =

    0.3409

y01_2 =

    0.3922

y02_2 =

    0.6555

y03_2 =

    0.1712

y0_star =

    0.4826

iter_cnt = 

    3
```

Note that you will get different results as these numbers are randomly generated.

---

## Edit per your comments

You want to modify the code such that `p1 > p2 > p3`.  Simply place an `if` statement inside your `else` statement that checks for this fact when you are generating `p1,p2,p3`.  If not, then reset all of the parameters back to the default then try again.

In other words:

```
clc;
clear;
y0_star = 1;
p1 = 1;
p2 = 1;
p3 = 1;
y01_2 = 0;
y02_2 = 0;
y03_2 = 0;
iter_cnt = 0;
while (y0_star > 0.5) %// Change - no need to check for sum not equaling to 1
    y0_star = 1 - 1 / (p1/(1 - y01_2) + p2/(1 - y02_2) + p3/(1 - y03_2));

    if (y0_star < 0.5) %// Change - no need to check if sum equals 1 since we're normalizing
        disp('no errors')
        break
    else
        p1 = rand;
        p2 = rand;
        p3 = rand;
        %// Change - as per your comment
        if (~( (p1 > p2) && (p2 > p3)))            
            y0_star = 1;
            p1 = 1;
            p2 = 1;
            p3 = 1;
            y01_2 = 0;
            y02_2 = 0;
            y03_2 = 0;
            continue;
        end         
        s = p1 + p2 + p3; %// Change - Find sum of p1 + p2 + p3
        p1 = p1 / s; %// Change - Divide by sum to ensure sum is 1
        p2 = p2 / s;
        p3 = p3 / s;
        y01_2 = rand;
        y02_2 = rand;
        y03_2 = rand;
    end

    iter_cnt = iter_cnt + 1;
    if iter_cnt > 10^6
        disp('error')
        break
    end
 end
```

When I do this, this is what I get:

```
p1 =

    0.5417    

p2 =

    0.4470

p3 =

    0.0113

y01_2 =

    0.3371

y02_2 =

    0.1622

y03_2 =

    0.7943

y0_star =

    0.2886

iter_cnt =

     3
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And one more question. Can I do something in order to make p1 > p2 > p3?